# Strange Text Placement on Android 5.0 Lollipop due to android.graphics.Paint.getTextSize()

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here are a few images I will reference in my post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bCln.jpg.

Right now, I am following the "Android Game Programming for Dummies" book to develop a simple 'Whack A Mole' android app, and I encountered a strange error. When I run the app on an emulator running Android 2.1, the text that indicates the number of moles "whacked" and the number of moles "missed" is placed correctly (first image).

However, when I run the app on my phone (a Samsung Galaxy S5 Active running Android 5.0), only the bottommost pixel of the text appears at the top of the screen (second image).

I think the root of the problem is here:

```
    private void draw (Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
            if(!onTitle) {
                canvas.drawText("Whacked: " + Integer.toString(molesWhacked), 10, blackPaint.getTextSize()+10, 
                        blackPaint);
                canvas.drawText("Missed: " + Integer.toString(molesMissed), screenW - (int)(200*drawScaleW), 
                        blackPaint.getTextSize()+10, blackPaint);
```

Here is a link to my source code:

WhackAMoleView.java: http://pastebin.com/ymMW2CUb

I have tried debugging the y position of the text with system.out.println statements, and what I have found is that adding "getTextSize()" to "10" returns "NaN." Since getTextSize() returns a float, I have tried converting 10 into a float by typing "10.0f," but the addition still returns "NaN." Strangely, if I change the y position of the "whack" text to:

```
canvas.drawText("Whacked: " + Integer.toString(molesWhacked), 10, (float)(blackPaint.getTextSize()+10.0), 
                        blackPaint);
```

The "whack" text starts displaying properly (third image), but if I change it for both the "whack" and the "miss" texts:

```
canvas.drawText("Whacked: " + Integer.toString(molesWhacked), 10, (float)(blackPaint.getTextSize()+10.0), 
                        blackPaint);

canvas.drawText("Missed: " + Integer.toString(molesMissed), screenW - (int)(200*drawScaleW), 
                        (float)(blackPaint.getTextSize()+10.0), blackPaint);
```

Both texts disappear once again (fourth image).

My question is: What is going on, and how can I fix it?

I know this is a lot of code, but I will highly appreciate any suggestions!

EDIT:

I just ran it on an emulator running Android 5.1.1, and the text placement was correct. I am beginning to think this is the result of hardware acceleration optimizations...

Comment: try to  blackPaint.setTextSize(the size you need) firstly. I think, this parameter is uninitialized, or damaged somewhere else in the code

Comment: Hm...here is my source code: http://pastebin.com/ymMW2CUb. I initialize it on line 208. Did I initialize it correctly?